# When pushing value to vector nothing happends

Tags: c++, vector, push

I`m trying to push values to vector. But it seems like its full of 0.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> a;
    int size = 5;
    int b;
    bool g = false; // In different cases I initialise of not 
    if (!g) a.resize(size); // initialise vector with such code

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    {

        if (!a.empty())
        {
            cout << "Type number ";
            cin >> b;
            a.push_back(b);
            cout << "a[" << i << "] = " << a[i] << ", i = " << i << ", b = " << b << endl;
        }
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Console code

```
Type number 0
a[0] = 0, i = 0, b = 0
Type number 1
a[1] = 0, i = 1, b = 1
Type number 2
a[2] = 0, i = 2, b = 2
Type number 3
a[3] = 0, i = 3, b = 3
Type number 4
a[4] = 0, i = 4, b = 4
```

Whats going on? I think there is a mistake but I cant get it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set the size of the vector, then it will have that size. Pushing back another element *adds* to the vector, increasing the vectors size. It doesn't change an existing elements.

It seems you want [`reserve`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) instead, which sets the capacity (and reserves memory) but doesn't set the size.

Comment: Beware that using `reserve` will make the `if (!a.empty())` false. That branch's condition will also need to be change though it's not clear to me what it's purpose is.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, I used such construction because in my main project i have more than 1 vector, and wich of them will be initialised and wich will not be I dont know at the time of the compilation. Thats why I used boolean parameter. Now, in this particular situation, I will be using `a.at(i)` against `a.push_back(b)`